# Wordpress nextpage display Previous 2 of 10 Next

Tags: wordpress, post, pagination

I'm using `wp_link_pages()` to split my post into multiple pages. I want to achieve something like this as shown in the image below. Instead of showing all the page numbers with links, I want it to show only this format (Current Page of Total Page). Please help me with the exact codes. Thank you so much in advance.

[image: Screenshot]

PS: I don't want to use plugins.

Comment: Doesn't wp_link_pages spit that by default? Do you have some link or something we can take a look at? I'm not sure if I understand your question since your description says something different to your image

Comment: yes, it automatically split when you use <!--nextpage-->, by default it shows page numbers like this <previous>1,2,3,4<next>. What I want to achieve is something like this <previous>2 of 4<next>.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution to this problem. I've got this inspiration from [source file](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.2/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L0) where function wp_link_pages is defined.

```
function page_pagination( $echo = 1 )
{

    global $page, $numpages, $multipage, $more;

    if( $multipage ) { //probably you should add && $more to this condition.
        $next_text = "next";
        $prev_text = "prev";

        if( $page < $numpages ) {
            $next = _wp_link_page( $i = $page + 1 );
            $next_link = $next . $next_text . "</a>";
        }

        if( $i = ( $page - 1 ) ) {
            $prev = _wp_link_page( $i );
            $prev_link = $prev . $prev_text . "</a>";
        }

        $output = 
        "<div class=\"prev-next-page\">"
        . $prev_link 
        . "<span class=\"page-counter\">{$page} of {$numpages}</span>"
        . $next_link
        . "</div>";

    }

    if( $echo ){
        echo $output;
    }

    return $output;

}
```

If you need more freedom you can always adapt this function to suit your purposes. Include function into wordpress loop! Like this for example:

```
if ( have_posts( ) ) {
    while ( have_posts( ) ) {
        the_post( ); 
        //rest of code
        the_content();
        page_pagination();
    } 
}
```

As you can see, there is "private" function _wp_link_page used to solve your problem. I don't like using "private" functions, but it solves our problem.